# Trying to get property of non-object on one to many relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

So, i'm trying to learn laravel and i kind of got stuck on one to many relationship. So, i have a page with 3 links on it, and logging into the db the click on those links. All good, i click on link, it registers in the db the id of the link but when i try to print them in the view i get "Trying to get property of non-object".

My models:

```
class NiceAction extends Model
{
    public function logs(){

        return $this->hasMany('App\NiceActionLog');

    }
}

class NiceActionLog extends Model
{
    public function log(){

        return $this->belongsTo('App\NiceAction');

    }
}
```

My controller:

This is how i log into the db on click:

```
public function getNiceAction($action, $name = null){
    if ($name == null) {
        $name = 'you';
    }
    $nice_action = NiceAction::where('name', $action)->first();
    $nice_action_log = new NiceActionLog();
    $nice_action->logs()->save($nice_action_log);
    return view('actions.nice', ['action' => $action, 'name' => $name]);
}
```

And this is how i pass the loggs to the view:

```
public function getHome(){
        $actions = NiceAction::all();
        $logged_actions = NiceActionLog::all();
        return view('home', ['actions' => $actions, 'logged_actions' => $logged_actions]);
    }
```

And this is in my view:

```
    @foreach($logged_actions as $loggedAction)
            <li>{{ $loggedAction->log->name}}</li>
    @endforeach
```

---

LATER EDIT:

My tabels looks like this if this could be the problem:

nice_action_logs table:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('nice_action_logs', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->integer('nice_action_id');
    });
}
```

nice_actions table:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('nice_actions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->integer('niceness');
    });
}
```

Comment: What will `{{ dd($loggedAction->log()->toSql()) }}` return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `getHome()` method has the following line:

```
$logged_actions = NiceAction::all();
```

I'm assuming this is actually meant to be:

```
$logged_actions = NiceActionLog::all();
```

---

Since you're still getting the error after correcting this, you probably have a `NiceActionLog` record that does not have an associated `NiceAction` record. Because of this, `$loggedAction->log` will be `null`, and then `$loggedAction->log->name` will give you the error you're seeing.

You can check to see if log exists before attempting to access a property on it:

```
@foreach($logged_actions as $loggedAction)
    <li>{{ $loggedAction->log ? $loggedAction->log->name : 'No Log' }}</li>
@endforeach
```

---

Based on your update with the table definitions, your `belongsTo` relationship is not defined correctly. The `belongsTo` side of the relationship builds the foreign key name based on the name of the relationship method. You've named your relationship method `log()`, so it will look for a field on the `nice_actions_logs` table named `log_id`. You either need to rename your relationship method to match the foreign key field, or you need to pass the foreign key field to use in as the second parameter.

```
class NiceActionLog extends Model
{
    // change the relationship method so the foreign key name will be correct
    public function nice_action() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\NiceAction');
    }
}
```

Or

```
class NiceActionLog extends Model
{
    // leave relationship method alone, but supply the foreign key to the relationship
    public function log() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\NiceAction', 'nice_action_id');
    }
}
```

The `hasMany` side of the relationship builds the foreign key name based on the class name, so since your class is named `NiceAction`, it will look for the `nice_action_id` field, which is correct. There is no need to change this relationship definition or name.

Comment: Oh, yeah. Thanks for that. I edited in the main post. But I still get the same error tho

Comment: it prints No log for every row in the log table.

Comment: @IonuțZamfir I have updated my answer based on the additional information in your question.

Comment: Oh. That make sense now. I marked this as answer. Ty for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to view what `$loggedAction` really contains:

```
@foreach($logged_actions as $loggedAction)
    <li>{{ var_dump($loggedAction)}}</li>
@endforeach
```

Then, look at the output, and see what's wrong.

Possible answers:

1. $loggedAction->log might be `null`
2. $loggedAction might be an array (not so possible)

You can check the logs variable before putting like this:

```
@foreach($logged_actions as $loggedAction)
    <li>
    @if (property_exists($loggedAction->log,"name"))
        {{$loggedAction->log->name}}
    @else
        No Log
    @endif
</li>
@endforeach
```

Comment: when i do the var_dump it gives me this which i kind of have no idea what doest it mean: http://prntscr.com/cc8thw  and when i do your @foreach i get No log on every li. But when i do {{ $loggedAction }} i get the exact datas from the log table in the db

Comment: and when i do {{ $loggedAction->log }} it gives me the numbers of LI equals to the rows in the log table but nothing on them so i guess the $loggedAction->log is null but i dont understand what i did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i've got it. I've changed my models into these and now works:

```
class NiceAction extends Model
{
    public function NiceAction(){ //changed function's name

        return $this->hasMany('App\NiceActionLog');

    }
}

class NiceActionLog extends Model
{
    public function NiceActionLog(){ // changed function's name

        return $this->belongsTo('App\NiceAction', 'nice_action_id'); // added nice_action_id parameter

    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you call the relation `NiceActionLog()`? It returns a `NiceAction` object. So you should call it `NiceAction()`, `niceAction()` or `action()`.

Comment: Well looks like the functions' name has to be the same as the table's name for this to work. And since my tabels are named NiceAction and NiceActionLog so the functions are.

Comment: You can give the relation any name you want. But the convention is to name it same as the **related** model.